# Bandwidth Speeds

Tags: cisco, snmp, bandwidth, internet

I have a Cisco Catalyst 6500 with the 720 Supe card. I would like to get the upload and download utilization of a specific port. I would like it from SNMP, I have looked for the correct MIB but no luck. The port I am trying to see is gi2/23.

Comment: Your request is a little bit broad; "get the internet upload and download utilization" doesn't have any specific meaning in this context.  Do you need the utilization of a specific port(s) on the 6500?  Or the throughput across the Sup 720 iteslf? Or something else entirely?   From what I can gather, a simple `snmpget` string executed by a server might serve you well, but I would need to know specifically what you're looking for to get more specific.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad/primarily opinion based - "the best" way doesn't mean much as the way your question is phrased and the lack of requirements/information isn't giving us much to go on to help with answering the question (as Brett has already pointed out :-) ).

Comment: Sorry, What I would like is the utilization of a specific port.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.  As it stands the question might still be too opinion based; "what is the best" can be very subjective.   I would suggest taking a look at using SNMPget to pull informaton on an interface.  Then asking a specific question if you get stuck.  Also you may want to check out Cisco's docs on [calculating usage with SNMP](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk648/tk362/technologies_tech_note09186a008009496e.shtml).

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: you need ifhcinoctets and ifhcoutoctets.  Remember that those are absolute byte counters so you have to do math between polls to derive bps.  Those MIB variables are indexed with ifname. Brett's comment has a link to a good Cisco doc

Comment: Okay so I understand how to calculate the utilization once I get the ifhcoutoctets and the ifhcinoctets but Im not sure what MIB to use to get the info.

Comment: ifhcinoctets and ifhcoutoctets are in if-mib: rfc2233

Comment: @MikePennington they're actually indexed with ifIndex (ifName is too)

Comment: @johnjensen you're correct, that is the most precise way to describe it

Comment: @Jonathan this question is still lacking too much information about your environment - even if these specifics were given, this question will turn into a "product recommendations" type question, and the answers will reflect that (this is something we have to avoid). Please clarify if you have a system available (and what platform it's running on, ie Linux/Windows/etc) to do the polling, and I can provide some general recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick-and-dirty way to get the current utilization would be to poll these OIDs from [OLD-CISCO-INTERFACES-MIB](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseMIB.do?local=en&step=2&mibName=OLD-CISCO-INTERFACES-MIB):

- locIfInBitsSec - 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.2.2.1.1.6.x
- locIfInPktsSec - 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.2.2.1.1.7.x
- locIfOutBitsSec - 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.2.2.1.1.8.x
- locIfOutPktsSec - 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.2.2.1.1.9.x

These give you the same numbers as the "input rate" and "output rate" lines from the output of `show interface`. Just replace the "x" with the interface index for Gig2/23 shown in `show snmp mib ifmib ifindex`. The MIB states that it's the "five minute exponentially-decayed moving average", but the actual rate matches whatever you've configured with `load-interval` on the interface (which defaults to 5 minutes).

These OIDs will give you a pretty good point-in-time measurement of the interface's utilization without requiring an external system to keep track of deltas between measurements. However, since it's an exponentially-decayed moving average, it may not be as accurate.